# Meaning of doubled parameter specification like f(x)(y) in JavaScript function call

Tags: javascript, redux

In JavaScript tutorial on Redux, there is a following JavaScript construct:

```
export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)(RemoveCounter);
```

Without going into depths of Redux (unless necessary), and I think `connect(..)` is a function call, how it is possible to specify the parameter twice, and how this is understood? If the complete code is required, it can be found [here](https://appdividend.com/2017/08/23/redux-tutorial-example-scratch/#Reducers).

Comment: this exists on es6?? Woww s new for me :D I'd search that explanation

Comment: There is nothing specific to ES6 in that syntax-- it is simply a function that itself returns a function-- it has been a feature of JavaScript since the beginning as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing specifically ES6 about this-- you are looking at a function that itself returns another function.  For example:

```
function addXMaker(x) {
    return function (num) {
        return num + x;
    } 
}

addXMaker(10)(5); // returns 15
```

This is perfectly valid in ES5, possible because in JavaScript functions are first-class citizens.

[`connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) accepts the config to map in state and dispatch, and returns a higher-order component, into which you can pass the component that you would like to receive the interface the HOC will inject.

Answer (score 1):

`connect()` returns a function, so the second set of parentheses is just calling the function that was returned. `RemoveCounter` is passed as the argument to it.

Answer (score 1):

The function `connect()` itself returns a function. The returned function can then have arguments passed into it.

```js
const add = (num1) => (
  (num2) => num1 + num2
)

console.log(
  add(1)(2)
)
```